# Driver for USB AVR JTAG-ISP device

Tags: usb, driver, avr, jtag

I've got a programming device called USB AVR JTAG-ISP v. 1.2.

Where can I find drivers and a good IDE for it?

Answer (score 5):

For Windows, AVR Studio 4 as per the other answer.

For Linux, you want the avr-gcc and [AVRDUDE](http://www.nongnu.org/avrdude/) packages from your OS distribution, plus your choice of C IDEs for Linux.

For OS X, you want [Crosspack](http://www.obdev.at/products/crosspack/index.html) and Xcode.

On Linux or OS X, depending on which device you are programming, you may need to download the [source for AVRDUDE](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/avrdude/) and rebuild it, which will require that you also get [libusb 0.1.12](http://www.libusb.org/) (not libusb 1.x).

Answer (score 2):

Try the "AVR Studio 4" on [Atmel's website](http://www.atmel.com/dyn/products/tools_mcu.asp?family_id=607).

Answer (score 1):

I find AVR studio to be infuriating, buggy and generally terrible.

Eclipse (available on all platforms) has wonderful end-to-end AVR integration available if you install the avr plugin, avr-gcc and avrdude.

If you're running on Ubuntu beware that it [doesn't always identify the ISP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5412727/avrisp-mkii-doesnt-work-with-avrdude-in-linux/5414566) right off the bat