# avrdude on ubuntu with JTAGICE mkII clone - problems connecting ATmega1280 (RSP_ILLEGAL_JTAG_ID)

Tags: avr, atmega, avrdude

Hopefully I've been struggling with this long enough to ask a question here...

I can't connect ATmega1280 with a cheaper version of JTAGICE mkII like [this one](http://www.pic16.com/en/wzcapi/avrjtagicemkii.htm). I'm trying to first set fuses for JTAG debugging. I've already done udev config as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5412727/avrisp-mkii-doesnt-work-with-avrdude-in-linux) (and [here](http://steve.kargs.net/bacnet/avr-isp-mkii-on-ubuntu-hardy/)).

**EDIT:** I'm able to connect my hardware on my computer via my JTAGICE in Windows using AVRStudio, so I'm already positive the wiring is ok.

All I'm getting is:

```
$ avrdude -P usb -c jtagmkii -p m1280 -U hfuse:w:0x1a:m

avrdude: jtagmkII_program_enable(): bad response to enter progmode command: RSP_ILLEGAL_JTAG_ID
avrdude: jtagmkII_program_enable(): bad response to enter progmode command: RSP_ILLEGAL_JTAG_ID
avrdude: JTAGEN fuse disabled?
avrdude: initialization failed, rc=-1
         Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
         this check.

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

I've read this can help solving JTAGICE problems. Sadly, I don't understand how it could help, but maybe you do:

```
$ avarice --part atmega1280 --mkII --jtag usb --read-fuses --read-lockbits --debug
AVaRICE version 2.10, Feb  8 2010 07:22:18

Defaulting JTAG bitrate to 250 kHz.

Found JTAG ICE, serno: 070000004693
JTAG config starting.
Attempting synchronisation at bitrate 19200

command[0x01, 1]: 01 
recv: 0x1b
recv: 0x00
recv: 0x00
recv: 0x1c
recv: 0x00
recv: 0x00
recv: 0x00
recv: 0x0e
sDATA: reading 28 bytes
read:  86 01 ff 26 04 00 ff 26 04 01 07 00 00 00 46 93 4a 54 41 47 49 43 45 6d 6b 49 49 00
recv: 0xb9
recv: 0xfe
CRC OK
Got message seqno 0 (command_sequence == 0)
response: 86 01 FF 26 04 00 FF 26 04 01 07 00 00 00 46 93 4A 54 41 47 49 43 45 6D 6B 49 49 00 
Found a device: JTAGICEmkII
Serial number:  07:00:00:00:46:93
JTAG ICE mkII sign-on message:
Communications protocol version: 1
M_MCU:
  boot-loader FW version:        255
  firmware version:              4.38
  hardware version:              0
S_MCU:
  boot-loader FW version:        255
  firmware version:              4.38
  hardware version:              1

command[0x02, 1]: 02 03 01 
recv: 0x1b
recv: 0x01
recv: 0x00
recv: 0x01
recv: 0x00
recv: 0x00
recv: 0x00
recv: 0x0e
sDATA: reading 1 bytes
read:  80
recv: 0xcd
recv: 0x83
CRC OK
Got message seqno 1 (command_sequence == 1)
response: 80 

command[0x0a, 1]: 0A 01 
recv: 0x1b
recv: 0x02
recv: 0x00
recv: 0x01
recv: 0x00
recv: 0x00
recv: 0x00
recv: 0x0e
sDATA: reading 1 bytes
read:  80
recv: 0x1d
recv: 0x09
CRC OK
Got message seqno 2 (command_sequence == 2)
response: 80 
Automatic device detection: 
command[0x03, 1]: 03 0E 
recv: 0x1b
recv: 0xff
recv: 0xff
recv: 0x06
recv: 0x00
recv: 0x00
recv: 0x00
recv: 0x0e
sDATA: reading 6 bytes
read:  e0 fe ff 00 00 00
recv: 0x82
recv: 0x16
CRC OK
Got message seqno 65535 (command_sequence == 3)

got asynchronous event: 0xe0
recv: 0x1b
recv: 0x03
recv: 0x00
recv: 0x05
recv: 0x00
recv: 0x00
recv: 0x00
recv: 0x0e
sDATA: reading 5 bytes
read:  81 ff ff ff ff
recv: 0x24
recv: 0x19
CRC OK
Got message seqno 3 (command_sequence == 3)
response: 81 FF FF FF FF 
JTAG id = 0xFFFFFFFF : Ver = 0xf : Device = 0xffff : Manuf = 0x7ff
Reported JTAG device ID: 0xFFFF
Looking for device: atmega1280
Configured for device ID: 0x9703 atmega1280 -- FORCED with atmega1280

command[0x0c, 1]: 0C FF FF FF FF FF 3D B9 F8 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF FF 1F E0 FF 1D A9 F8 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 73 FF 3F FF F7 3F F7 3F F7 3F 5F 3F 37 37 36 00 00 00 00 00 FF 0F 00 00 F7 3F 36 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 73 FF 3F F8 F7 3F F7 3F F7 3F 5F 2F 36 36 36 00 00 00 00 00 FF 0F 00 00 F7 3F 36 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 31 57 3B 00 01 08 00 FE 00 00 36 01 00 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 3E 3D 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 02 00 00 00 3C 1F 00 
recv: 0x1b
recv: 0x04
recv: 0x00
recv: 0x01
recv: 0x00
recv: 0x00
recv: 0x00
recv: 0x0e
sDATA: reading 1 bytes
read:  80
recv: 0xac
recv: 0x14
CRC OK
Got message seqno 4 (command_sequence == 4)
response: 80 
JTAG config complete.

command[0x14, 1]: 14 
recv: 0x1b
recv: 0x05
recv: 0x00
recv: 0x01
recv: 0x00
recv: 0x00
recv: 0x00
recv: 0x0e
sDATA: reading 1 bytes
read:  a9
recv: 0xd0
recv: 0x29
CRC OK
Got message seqno 5 (command_sequence == 5)
response: A9 

command[0x14, 2]: 14 
recv: 0x1b
recv: 0x06
recv: 0x00
recv: 0x01
recv: 0x00
recv: 0x00
recv: 0x00
recv: 0x0e
sDATA: reading 1 bytes
read:  a9
recv: 0x00
recv: 0xa3
CRC OK
Got message seqno 6 (command_sequence == 6)
response: A9 

command[0x14, 3]: 14 
recv: 0x1b
recv: 0x07
recv: 0x00
recv: 0x01
recv: 0x00
recv: 0x00
recv: 0x00
recv: 0x0e
sDATA: reading 1 bytes
read:  a9
recv: 0xbf
recv: 0x22
CRC OK
Got message seqno 7 (command_sequence == 7)
response: A9 

command[0x14, 4]: 14 
recv: 0x1b
recv: 0x08
recv: 0x00
recv: 0x01
recv: 0x00
recv: 0x00
recv: 0x00
recv: 0x0e
sDATA: reading 1 bytes
read:  a9
recv: 0x0d
recv: 0x93
CRC OK
Got message seqno 8 (command_sequence == 8)
response: A9 

command[0x14, 5]: 14 
recv: 0x1b
recv: 0x09
recv: 0x00
recv: 0x01
recv: 0x00
recv: 0x00
recv: 0x00
recv: 0x0e
sDATA: reading 1 bytes
read:  a9
recv: 0xb2
recv: 0x12
CRC OK
Got message seqno 9 (command_sequence == 9)
response: A9 

command[0x14, 6]: 14 
recv: 0x1b
recv: 0x0a
recv: 0x00
recv: 0x01
recv: 0x00
recv: 0x00
recv: 0x00
recv: 0x0e
sDATA: reading 1 bytes
read:  a9
recv: 0x62
recv: 0x98
CRC OK
Got message seqno 10 (command_sequence == 10)
response: A9 

command[0x14, 7]: 14 
recv: 0x1b
recv: 0x0b
recv: 0x00
recv: 0x01
recv: 0x00
recv: 0x00
recv: 0x00
recv: 0x0e
sDATA: reading 1 bytes
read:  a9
recv: 0xdd
recv: 0x19
CRC OK
Got message seqno 11 (command_sequence == 11)
response: A9 

command[0x14, 8]: 14 
recv: 0x1b
recv: 0x0c
recv: 0x00
recv: 0x01
recv: 0x00
recv: 0x00
recv: 0x00
recv: 0x0e
sDATA: reading 1 bytes
read:  a9
recv: 0xd3
recv: 0x85
CRC OK
Got message seqno 12 (command_sequence == 12)
response: A9 

command[0x14, 9]: 14 
recv: 0x1b
recv: 0x0d
recv: 0x00
recv: 0x01
recv: 0x00
recv: 0x00
recv: 0x00
recv: 0x0e
sDATA: reading 1 bytes
read:  a9
recv: 0x6c
recv: 0x04
CRC OK
Got message seqno 13 (command_sequence == 13)
response: A9 

command[0x14, 10]: 14 
recv: 0x1b
recv: 0x0e
recv: 0x00
recv: 0x01
recv: 0x00
recv: 0x00
recv: 0x00
recv: 0x0e
sDATA: reading 1 bytes
read:  a9
recv: 0xbc
recv: 0x8e
CRC OK
Got message seqno 14 (command_sequence == 14)
response: A9 
JTAG ICE: Cannot synchronise
```

The device is being recognized on my system

```
$ lsusb 
Bus 002 Device 012: ID 03eb:2103 Atmel Corp. JTAG ICE mkII
```

It's also not behind any USB hub. I triple checked all connections. Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

avrice is connecting to the unit fine, but the unit doesn't seem to be communicating with the target device. Are you sure it is connected and powered on?

[This document](http://www.atmel.com/dyn/resources/prod_documents/doc2587.pdf) may help you decipher what the jtag unit is responding.

Comment: Yes I am, and the wiring is ok too, I already confirmed it. I edited my question to make it clear. Thanks for the document, I'll take a look.