# Problems with the AVR-ISP-MKII under ubuntu

Tags: avr, avrdude, ubuntu-13.04

I'm hoping for a bit of help.
I'm trying to get an AVR-ISP-MKII working under Ubuntu 13.04 with avrdude.

I have followed a post on here with a similar problem and that seems to have moved me on a little.

The post is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5412727/avrisp-mkii-doesnt-work-with-avrdude-in-linux).

So far I have :-
1. upgraded the firmware in the programmer form the suppliers site. (This was done with dfu-programmer and code from Olimex.com)

2. updated my rules file. /etc/udev/rules.d/60-avrisp.rules to include the following :-

SUBSYSTEM!="usb", ACTION!="add", GOTO="avrisp_end"

ATTR{idVendor}=="03eb", ATTR{idProduct}=="2103", MODE="660", GROUP="dialout"

ATTR{idVendor}=="03eb", ATTR{idProduct}=="2104", MODE="660", GROUP="dialout"

ATTR{idVendor}=="03eb", ATTR{idProduct}=="2107", MODE="660", GROUP="dialout"

ATTR{idVendor}=="1781", ATTR{idProduct}=="0c9f", MODE="660", GROUP="dialout"

LABEL="avrisp_end"

and restarted udev.

If I now try to program an avr with this setup I get :-

cmd>$ avrdude -p m1284p -c avrispmkII -P usb -B 22 -U flash:w:optiboot_atmega1284p.hex

avrdude: stk500v2_command(): command failed
avrdude: stk500v2_program_enable(): bad AVRISPmkII connection status: Unknown status 0x00
avrdude: initialization failed, rc=-1
         Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
         this check.

avrdude done.  Thank you.

Any help would be much appreciated. I have wasted an entire day on this. All so that I can program a boot loader into a chip. Once done I can then program the thing via usb.....
It's driving me nuts.

If you need any more info please let me know.

Thanks,

Rob

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it is not problem with `udev` settings.

Try running `avrdude` with `sudo` once, if it has the same error message it is a connection problem.